# Why does Tkinter freeze when packing a scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to attach a scrollbar to a list box in Tkinter, but whenever the code reaches one of the .pack() lines it freezes... any idea why? (I've experimented with running an example code that does the same thing that I found on the internet and that worked fine).

```
        #Read Box
    self.scrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frame)
    #self.scrollbar.pack(side=Tkinter.RIGHT, fill=Tkinter.Y)
    self.read = Tkinter.Listbox(self.frame, width=50, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.read.grid(row=1,column=2)
    #self.read.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT, fill=Tkinter.BOTH)
    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.read.yview)
```

Any idea why this code does not work?

---

Updated code:

```
        #Read Box
    self.scrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frame)
    self.scrollbar2.grid(sticky=Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S) #row=1, column=2 side=Tkinter.RIGHT, fill=Tkinter.Y

    self.read = Tkinter.Listbox(self.frame, width=50, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.read.grid(row=1,column=2) #side=Tkinter.LEFT, fill=Tkinter.BOTH

    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.read.yview)
```

---

Alright that was a minor mistake (I confused scrollbar and scrollbar2). Anyway now I have this code:

```
        #Read Box
    self.scrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frame)
    self.scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=2)

    self.read = Tkinter.Listbox(self.frame, width=50, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.read.grid(row=1,column=2)

    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.read.yview)
```

This does not freeze and the scrollbar appears, but they are not connected to (or have any control over) the listbox. With regard to the rest of the code, it is all grid statements, no pack.

---

I found the problem, the scrollbar was missing sticky=Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S. Here's the finished code (with added horizontal bars).

```
        #Read Box
    self.scrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frame)
    self.scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S)

    self.hbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
    self.hbar.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)

    self.read = Tkinter.Listbox(self.frame, width=50, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=self.hbar.set)
    self.read.grid(row=1,column=2)

    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.read.yview)
    self.hbar.config(command=self.read.xview)
```

Comment: Your code samples do not provide enough information. If the code is freezing it usually means one of two things: you have created your own infinite (or long running) loop, or you are mixing grid and pack in the same container. It's impossible to tell which is your problem with just the tiny bit of code you posted.

Comment: If your code is not frozen anymore, then your question has already found an answer! So, if my answer was right, please accept it. Now about scrollbar: maybe you should use `self.mainloop()` command?

Comment: Your answer has been accepted. I'm already calling a mainloop() though?

Comment: Thanks :-) Now about your new problem: I don't know if `self.scrollbar.config(...)` is the correct one, I've always used `.configure`. I'm running Python 2.6 so this could be a difference, but I doubt it. Could you make a try using `self.scrollbar.configure(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you're mixing `pack` and `grid` at same level (i.e. not inside two separate `Frame` or else). This will make your app to freeze, as described in documentation.

So what you should do is to `.grid` your scrollbar :-)

More material: as said above, you can mix different window managers, but not inside the same frame. What is below is legal and will work:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
f1 = Frame(root)
f1.pack()
Label(f1, text='some text').grid(row=0, column=0)
Button(f1, text='Button').grid(row=1, column=0)

f2 = Frame(root)
f2.pack()
Label(f2, text="content of Frame 2").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I changed the code so it had no pack statements for the frame and I used grids and it still won't work? I replaced the packs with this:
self.scrollbar2.grid(row=1, column=2, side=Tkinter.RIGHT, fill=Tkinter.Y)

Comment: Well, I don't know what is not working now, but I bet you get some error like `unknown argument for grid: -side`. `grid` is not using the same arguments as `pack`; equivalent to `fill=Tkinter.Y` would be `sticky=N+S`. Could you please try it, and publish your updated code?

Comment: Both `self.scrollbar2.grid(sticky=Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S)` and `self.scrollbar2.grid(row=1 column=2)` cause Tkinter to freeze, if I change them all to pack, Tkinter does not freeze, but I have no control over widget position.

Comment: Sorry it's hard to tell now, could you please publish your updated code in your question? use three hyphens to create some separation.